# In init.rc chmod system file rw

Tags: android, system, init

There is a file named bootanimation.zip in /system/media:

```
1853 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.1M 2018-07-10 17:29 bootanimation.zip
```

I want to make it writeable.

So I do this in init.rc:

```
on fs
+   mount ext4 /dev/block/platform/mstar_mci.0/by-name/system /system wait rw
+   chmod 0777 /system/media/bootanimation.zip
 mount_all /fstab.m7221
```

But it is useless.The bootanimation.zip still is `-rw-r--r--`.

How can I make /system/media/bootanimation.zip rw in init.rc ?

Can someone tell me how to debug init.rc , I can not see any log!